# Sort by AVG(rating desc)

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello: I want to display products from the highest rating to the lower, i made this sql query but it didn't work, my while loop only get me 1 product without any rating, so is there any other way or an other sql query does  what i want to do?

```
select productT.dateOfInsert, productT.discount FROM productT 
INNER JOIN ratingT 
ON productT.id = ratingT.id_product 
WHERE productT.typeStore = 'Wholesale' and productT.typeStore = 'paid' 
order by AVG(ratingT.rating desc)
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images. And take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with group by

```
select productT.dateOfInsert, productT.discount FROM productT 
INNER JOIN ratingT 
ON productT.id = ratingT.id_product 
WHERE productT.typeStore = 'Wholesale' and productT.typeStore = 'paid' 
group by productT.dateOfInsert, productT.discount
order by AVG(ratingT.rating) desc
```

Comment: Will execute, but will the result make any sense? date/discount vs average rating...